# Web Method Not accessing in Local Read Network By ip

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asmx

i am trying to access web method using Machine Ip(like http://192.168.0.150/projectname/serviceName.asmx/methodname).

i just host my project on my server iis 7 and trying to access web method in my uwp application.

But when i am trying to access above url i am getting below error

> Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in
>   '/HelloWorld'.

when ever i am trying to same web method access in my server then it works fine.
i already added httpget and httppost protocol in my web config file.

but still i am not getting any success.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ajaxToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
        <remove name="Documentation"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701" />
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+" />
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="SQLDbConnection" connectionString="Server=192.168.0.150; Database=InfocastDB; User Id=aba; password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
    <add key="EnableSimpleMembership" value="true" />
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0" />
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false" />
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
    <add key="vs:EnableBrowserLink" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory"
           verb="*" path="*.asmx"
           type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
           resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="index.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
   <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.2.14234" newVersion="1.5.2.14234"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
      multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

And my *.asmx file code is as below

```
public class ImageGallaryService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

    [WebMethod]
    public string HelloWorld()
    {
        return "Hello World";
    }}
```